# Multiple Solutions of Eigenvalue Laplacian Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

I am reading a paper in which they are talking about a probability distribution converging to the 'principal eigenfunction of the Laplacian problem':
$$
-\Delta U(x)=U(x), ||x||<R \\
U(x)>0, ||x||<R \\
U(x)=0, ||x||\geq R \\
\int U(x) dx=1
$$
where $U:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$. The fact that they said *principal eigenfunction* (and the context of the paper) seemed to imply to me that there are multiple solutions and we are in fact only looking at one of them, but I can't see that there are any solutions other than: $U(x)=\frac{1}{2}cos(x)$, $R=\pi/2$. Am I missing some family of solutions? Am I being stupid?

Comment: Isn't it a Bessel?

Comment: Bessel's DE for $\alpha=0$ would be $x^2\Delta U(x) + xU'(x) + x^2 U(x)=0$ rather than $x^2\Delta U(x) + x^2 U(x)=0$ as above, no?

Comment: You need to write the Laplacian in (hyper) spherical coordinates.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Are you saying this means that there is indeed a unique solution? @user619894

Comment: I am not answering the question. I am commenting that the eigen-solutions to spherically symmetric d dimensional Laplacians are spherical Bessel functions.